# Why is $p(A,B)p(C|B) = p(A,B,C)$?

Tags: probability

I understand that $p(A,B,C)=p(A,B|C)p(C) = p(A,B)p(C|A,B)$ but I don't see how to use this to solve this problem.

Comment: Are there any conditions under which the equation could be true?

Comment: in general the equation in the title is not true. It is true, of course, if and only if $P(C|A\cap B)= P(C|B)$. Which is true, for example, when $A$ and $C$ are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relation doesn't hold generally. It holds only if$$p(C|B)=p(C|A,B)$$i.e. the random variables $C|B$ and $A|B$ be independent which means that $$A\to B\to C$$ forms a Markov chain.